# Stop duplicating SEO meta tags while product duplicating

Tags: magento2, product, meta-tags, duplicate

How to stop duplicating only SEO Meta tags when duplicating product in Magento 2. Can someone guide me how to get it?

Comment: If my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: I usually duplicate products to create an another one from the previous configuration to eliminate creating from scratch. So setting up canonical URL is not a solution for my problem. During duplicating a product I don't want the meta fields to be filled.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

If you go to your admin panel and navigate to

> Admin Store -> Configuration -> Catalog > Search Engine Optimization

In the Search Engine Optimisation tab, you can find the following two entries:

**Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories**

**Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products**

This will not delete the redundant pages but will add the same canonical links in the head of your HTML files

Now when google indexes your site, it will probably still see both links, but since you added a canonical link to it, Google will now know that both links are the same page.